# RN FlatList does not render items (hooks + redux + thunk)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

hope you are all well.
Need some guidance. Any piece of advice would be appreciated
I 've spent quite a bit of time looking for a solution but still for some reason I am still missing something

PROBLEM: FlatList (sometimes) does not render items

- FlatList gets data from redux
- useEffect dispatches a thunk, triggers a remote API call
- page variable is held for pagination purposes
- I can see that redux store being updated, but somehow FlatList does not update

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

useEffect(() => {
async function dispatchAsyncAction() {
  await dispatch(getData(page))
}
dispatchAsyncAction()
}, [page])

const handleOnEndReached = () => {
setPage(previousPage => previousPage + 1)
}
return (
<FlatList
  data={store.GetState().data}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
/>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, it took me a while to figure out that instead of

```
store.GetState().data
```

I should have used:

```
const data = useSelector(state= state.data)
```